# $\{C_1, ..., C_m\}$ is unsatisfiable if and only if $\backsim C_1 \vee... \vee \backsim C_m$ is valid

Tags: logic

I'm having trouble understanding what it means for the set to be unsatisfiable and for the logical proposition to be valid. Do all of the elements have to be false for it to be unsatisfiable, and do they all have to be false in just one instance?

If $\backsim C_1 \vee... \vee \backsim C_m$ is valid, doesn't it have to be true under every interpretation? But how could it possibly be true under the interpretation where $C_1, ..., C_m$ are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will start from the definition.

We have that the set $\{C_1, ..., C_m\}$ is *satisfiable* iff :

> there exists an *interpretation* $I$ such that each of $C_i$ are *true* in $I$.

So, we have that it is *unsatisfiable* iff "**not** exists an interpretation ..."

Now, we will work with the properties of *quantifiers* in the meta-theory.

So, saying that "not exists an interpretation such that all of ..." can be rewrited as [using the following property of quantifiers : $\lnot \exists \forall$ is equivalent to : $\forall \exists \lnot$] :

> for all interpretation $I$ there exists (at least) one of $C_i$ that is **not** *true* in $I$, i.e. that is *false* in $I$.

But now, if $C_i$ is *false* in $I$, then $\lnot C_i$ is *true* in $I$.

So, we have that the set $\{C_1, ..., C_m\}$ is *unsatisfiable* iff :

> for all interpretation $I$ there exists (at least) one of $C_i$ such that $\lnot C_i$ is *true* in $I$.

Now, using truth-table for *disjunction*, if (at least) one of $\lnot C_i$ is *true* in $I$, then the *disjunction* $\lnot C_1 \lor ... \lor \lnot C_m$ is *true* in $I$.

Putting all together, we have that : the set is *unsatisfiable* iff

> for all interpretation $I$ , $\lnot C_1 \lor ... \lor \lnot C_m$ is *true* in $I$.

And this means exactly that :

> $\lnot C_1 \lor ... \lor \lnot C_m$ is *valid*